# Как скрыть полный текст описания в выводимых товарах?

Tags: html, css

style.css

```css
        .product-information p {
           color: #696763;
           font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
           margin-bottom: 5px;
           overflow: hidden;

          }
```

index.html

```html
   <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                
                    
                     <?= Html::img($mainImg->getUrl('207x183'), ['alt' => $hit->name])?>

                  <h2>$<?= $hit->price?></h2>
                    <p><a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['product/view', 'id' => '7']) ?>"><?= $hit->name?></a></p>
                    <a href="<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/add', 'id' => $hit->id])?>" data-id="<?= $hit->id?>" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

если через  "overflow: hidden;", то так не получается

Comment: покажите не начальный код а уже готовый варыан без php-кода

Answer (score 0):

style.css

```css
p {
     width: 80%;
     overflow: hidden;
     white-space: nowrap;
     word-wrap: normal; /* для IE */
     padding-left: 40px;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в css    .product-information p { display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Можно скрыть двумя способами через css, с помощью display: none и с помощью JS - это $("#idorclassblock").hide().